# after removing cookies it's getting null values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cookies

I have asp.net web application in vb. When users login cookies gets created and it stores users id in cookies. Now when user logs out it should delete or remove cookies from browser but it's not happening. After log out only userid gets deleted from browser but cookies remains null which creating problem in application. Please help to delete that particular cookie.

```
Protected Sub logout_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles logout.Click
        Response.Cookies("chkusername").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
        Response.Redirect("order-form.aspx")
End Sub
```

To check cookies I used below code

```
Private Sub Online_Medicines_order_online_Default_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("chkusername") Is Nothing Then
            userID.Text = Request.Cookies("chkusername").Value
        Else
            userID.Text = "No user Found"
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What kind of problems?

Comment: @Imad Like I have placed condition in my code that if there are no cookie then it should redirect to login page and if cookie is there then continue. But because here cookies("chkusername ") gets null values then it continues without userID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not adding expired cookie to `Response` object.

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies("chkusername");
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```